# Oracle 11g Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am having an issue linking my main table "MAINtbl" in my first query to my subquery. I am trying to take the results given in the "MAINtbl" and join the data to another table "WWPMARS.GPS_CLI_PRD_BASE_INFO F", by certain key fields.

---

```
select F.CNTRCT_NBR, F.CNTRCT_LI_NBR, F.BASE_PRC, F.PRD_EFCTV_DT from WWPMARS.GPS_CLI_PRD_BASE_INFO F
inner join ( 
SELECT C.CNTRCT_NBR, C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR, MAX(D.PRD_EFCTV_DT)
  FROM WWPMARS.GPS_CNTRCT_LINE_ITM C, WWPMARS.GPS_CNTRCT_LI_PRD D
 WHERE     (    ( (C.CNTRCT_TYPE_CD = 'B') AND (C.CNTRCT_CTG_CD = 'ST'))
            AND (D.TOT_PRC_ADD_ON_PRC <> '0')
            and C.CNTRCT_NBR||C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR ='3VLZ0000')
       AND (D.PRD_EFCTV_DT <= CURRENT_DATE)
       AND C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR = D.CNTRCT_LI_NBR
       AND C.CNTRCT_NBR = D.CNTRCT_NBR 
       group by C.CNTRCT_NBR, C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR) MAINtbl
       on F.CNTRCT_NBR = C.CNTRCT_NBR and F.CNTRCT_LI_NBR = C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR ;
```

Comment: This error popping up is; ORA-00904: "C"."CNTRCT_LI_NBR": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias `C` is only visible inside the subquery, not outside of it. You are, however, trying to use it outside (right at the end). Change it to `MAINtbl.CNTRCT_LI_NBR` at then end, as in:

```
select F.CNTRCT_NBR, F.CNTRCT_LI_NBR, F.BASE_PRC, F.PRD_EFCTV_DT 
from WWPMARS.GPS_CLI_PRD_BASE_INFO F
inner join ( 
SELECT C.CNTRCT_NBR, C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR, MAX(D.PRD_EFCTV_DT)
  FROM WWPMARS.GPS_CNTRCT_LINE_ITM C, WWPMARS.GPS_CNTRCT_LI_PRD D
 WHERE     (    ( (C.CNTRCT_TYPE_CD = 'B') AND (C.CNTRCT_CTG_CD = 'ST'))
            AND (D.TOT_PRC_ADD_ON_PRC <> '0')
            and C.CNTRCT_NBR||C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR ='3VLZ0000')
       AND (D.PRD_EFCTV_DT <= CURRENT_DATE)
       AND C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR = D.CNTRCT_LI_NBR
       AND C.CNTRCT_NBR = D.CNTRCT_NBR 
       group by C.CNTRCT_NBR, C.CNTRCT_LI_NBR) MAINtbl
       on F.CNTRCT_NBR = C.CNTRCT_NBR 
       and F.CNTRCT_LI_NBR = MAINtbl.CNTRCT_LI_NBR ; -- changed here!
```